# ASP.NET Web Service ignores [NonSerialized] hook

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, soap

I'm trying to implement a SOAP service in ASP.NET using C# so I can consume it with Flex - but that's the next step. The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to communicate with a server-side class which has an `XmlNamespaceManager` field within a `[Serializable]` class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Site {
...
public XmlNamespaceManager xmlNS;
...
}
```

I've tried appending the `[NonSerialized]` hook onto the problematic field, but my SOAP service doesn't seem to be obeying my instructions. Here's the service:

```
public class DotNetWikiService : WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public Article doWork(Site ws, String title)
    {
        Page thePage = new Page(ws, title);
        thePage.Load();

        if (thePage.Exists() == false)
        {
            return new Article(title, "Wiki page contents are empty.");
        }

        return new Article(title, thePage.text);
    }
}
```

and here's the error I get when I try and run the .asmx file:

> To be XML serializable, types which inherit from IEnumerable must have 
>   an implementation of Add(System.Object) at all levels of their inheritance 
>   hierarchy. System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager does not implement Add(System.Object).

Now, I'm aware that `XmlNamespaceManager`s are not serializable, so I've tried to indicate this, but something's going awry and I don't know what to do.

Help, please? :D

Comment: In addition, I've also tried making my own `XmlNamespaceManager` which inherits the original and does implement `Add` but then of course, the original still doesn't implement `Add`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to reproduce your issue and in my little test seem to have resolved it...

I got the same errors as you initially but the important thing here is not the error but the stack trace. Here's a little snip of what I got and I expect you would've seen something similar:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetEnumeratorElementType(Type type, TypeFlags& flags) +1354352
System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.ImportTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo memberInfo, Boolean directReference) +5553239
```

So we get a hint here that the serializer being used is the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) based on the `System.Xml.Serialization` namespace which is referenced in the stack trace. But, if we take a look at the `[NonSerialize]` [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx) we can see in the notes that it applies to BinaryFormatter and SoapFormatter but not when we want to use the XmlSerializer class. In that case we have to use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore.aspx) attribute.

Doing this turns your definition for this public member into:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public XmlNamespaceManager xmlNS;
```

I made a little test class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Site
{
    public string X { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public XmlNamespaceManager xmlNS;
}
```

And returned it from a service method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public Site HelloWorld()
    {
        Site toReturn = new Site();
        toReturn.X = "hello world";

        return toReturn;
    }
```

Ran that up, and it appeared in the browser. Tested the method and it returned "hello world" in a SOAP structure.

Comment: This. Soap is an xml format, and so uses xml serialization attributes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for. :) Although isn't it weird that SOAP services don't use `SoapFormatter` by default?

Comment: It's likely because `SoapFormatter` has been deprecated since .NET 2.0  but since the name was taken they couldn't name the replacement serializer `SoapFormatter`....